# using checkboxes for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script. Everything is working except I need to make it work with multi-able items. The first set of work perfectly, but I can seam to replicate it on the second and third set of check boxes.

```js
$(".checkall").on('change', function()
    {

        // all normal checkboxes will have a class "chk_xxxxxx"
        // where "xxxx" is the name of the location, e.g. "chk_wales"

        // get the class name from the id of the "check all" box
        var checkboxesClass = '.chk_' + $(this).attr("id");

        // now get all boxes to check
        var boxesToCheck = $(checkboxesClass);

        // check all the boxes
        boxesToCheck.prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

$("#check1 input[type=checkbox], #wales").on("change", function()
    {
        checkBoxes();
    });

    function checkBoxes()
    {

        $("#checked").empty();
        if($("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]").length)
        {

            $("#wales").prop("checked", true);

            // Display the id of the "check all" box
            $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + "<h3>Wales</h3>");

        }
        else
        {
            $("#wales").prop("checked", false);
            $("#check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function()
            {
                $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br>");
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
  <label for="wales" >Check All</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1" >Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2" >Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3" >Item 3</label>-->

  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
<label for="wales">Check All</label>
<section id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>
</section>

  <hr />
  <input type="checkbox" id="west" class="checkall" value="3">
  <label for="west">Check All</label>
  <section id="check2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem4" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem4">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem5" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem5">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem6" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem6">Item 3</label>
  </section>
  <hr />

  <input type="checkbox" id="east" class="checkall" value="5">
  <label for="east">Check All</label>
    <section id="check3">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem7" value="6" class="chk_east">
      <label for="checkItem7">Item 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem8" value="6" class="chk_east">
      <label for="checkItem8">Item 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem9" value="6" class="chk_east">
      <label for="checkItem9">Item 3</label>
  </section>
<p>You have selected:</p>

<div id="checked">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with your ID's

Answer (score 0):

remove `checkBoxes()` method and replace the last event handlers as (check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vpujq3n/2/))

```
//put the event handler directly on the checkboxes inside the section
$( "section input[type='checkbox']" ).on("change", function()
{
    console.log( $( this ) );
    //get the handle to the parent section 
    var $parentSection = $( this ).parent();
    //compare the number of checked checkboxes with total one 
    if( $parentSection.find( "input[type='checkbox']:checked" ).length == $parentSection.find( "input[type=checkbox]" ).length )
    {
        $parentSection.prev().prev().prop("checked", true);
        //write checkall's textbox id
        $("#checked").append( "<h3>" + $parentSection.prev().prev().attr( "id" ) + "</h3>");
    }
    else
    {
        $parentSection.prev().prev().prop("checked", false);
        //write each and every checked box's text
        $parentSection.find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function()
        {
            $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Explain your code. It's not really clear for the OP.

Comment: @KeesSonnema done, let me know if anything else is required

Comment: It's fine now :) (I did understand it, but make sure you add comments for OP)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i have been trying to get this to work but i am struggling ples see js fiddle http://jsbin.com/besazijure/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @DanielEdwards I am not able to access jsbin, please post a fiddle

Comment: thanks for the update, this is very close :), but when i click on the first check all it is ment to display ID wales and not display item 1,2,3 , same goes for the other ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98577/discussion-between-daniel-edwards-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet should fulfill your requirements. Hope this will help you.

```js
var checkedDiv = $("#checked");

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.className == 'checkall') {
    var section = $(this).nextAll('section:first');
    section.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  } else {
    var parentSection = $(this).parent();
    var checkall = parentSection.prevAll(".checkall:first")
    var isEqual = parentSection.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == parentSection.find("input[type=checkbox]").length;
    checkall.prop("checked", isEqual);
  }

  checkedDiv.html('');

  $('.checkall').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      checkedDiv.append('<h3>' + this.id + '</h3><br/>');
    } else {
      var section = $(this).nextAll('section:first');
      section.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        checkedDiv.append($(this).next().text() + "<br>");
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="wales" class="checkall" value="1">
<label for="wales">Check All</label>
<section id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem1">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem2">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3" value="2" class="chk_wales">
    <label for="checkItem3">Item 3</label>
</section>

<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="west" class="checkall" value="3">
<label for="west">Check All</label>
<section id="check2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem4" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem4">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem5" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem5">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem6" value="4" class="chk_west">
    <label for="checkItem6">Item 3</label>
</section>
<hr />

<input type="checkbox" id="east" class="checkall" value="5">
<label for="east">Check All</label>
<section id="check3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem7" value="6" class="chk_east">
    <label for="checkItem7">Item 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem8" value="6" class="chk_east">
    <label for="checkItem8">Item 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem9" value="6" class="chk_east">
    <label for="checkItem9">Item 3</label>
</section>

<p>You have selected:</p>
<div id="checked"></div>
```

Comment: ah close but not quite, for example i need the wales tag to disappear when it is unchecked if one of the items is unchecked, but if all the items are checked then just the wales show like this: https://jsbin.com/rucemacigu/1/edit?html,js,output